# Why does resharper class this as an improvement

Tags: c#, resharper

Why does resharper convert the following code:

```
if (a && !b && c)
{
    do_something();
}
```

to

```
if (!a || b|| !c)
    continue;
do_something();
```

I cannot see how one is an improvement on the other. 
(obviously this code is nested in a foreach loop, hence the use of the continue keyword).

Comment: Like basically all refactors ever, it can depend on personal preference or the specific context as to whether or not the refactor is an improvement or not.  If you prefer it, use it, if you don't, then don't.  By definition, the refactor is going to be functionally equivalent either way.

Comment: Resharper will always take the first exit.  if it was a function it would try to return.  It is done to avoid nesting.  in your case there really is no difference.

Comment: It reduces nesting if your `do_something();` snippet is big instead of a single call.

Comment: This is classified as a refactoring (hammer icon), not as an improvement (light bulb). As others said, refactorings are just possible changes, not necessarily improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I had already made the decision to ignore the possible change as it was way less readable for me. Im not too concerned with optimizations for my current project but thought it was worth asking the question to further my understanding. Your responses have compounded what i thought already. Many thanks.